# alternate appspec.yml location for AWS CodePipeline/CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

i'm learning AWS-based continuous integration and have a basic CodeCommit → CodePipeline → CodeDeploy workflow setup per the [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/getting-started-cc.html). when i push to CodeCommit, CodePipeline triggers a build in CodeDeploy, however it does not find my `appspec.yml` manifest because it's not in the root of my repository.

how do i configure CodePipeline/CodeDeploy to look for `appspec.yml` under the subdirectory `inst/aws/` instead of the repository root? i don't want to restructure my repo (which also has non-AWS content) just to accommodate a vendor-specific preference.

Answer (score 2):

By default CodeDeploy agent looks at the root of your bundle for appspec.yml. Unfortunately you can't configure the location of the appspec.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the use of AppSpecTemplatePath.

> The file name of the AppSpec file stored in the pipeline source file
> location, such as your pipeline's CodeCommit repository. The default
> file name is appspec.yaml. If your AppSpec file has the same name and
> is stored at the root level in your file repository, you do not need
> to provide the file name. If the path is not the default, enter the
> path and file name.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-ECSbluegreen.html#action-reference-ECSbluegreen-type